# setting older kernel version as default

Tags: 20.04, kernel

My OS version is **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. Recently I got a kernel update to version **5.8.0-38** but then I was facing a lot of hardware issues. Now I am temporarily on kernel version **5.8.0-36 generic**. How do I set this particular version as default. I am completely new to Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *simplest* solution might be to enable Grub's `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT` feature. Try this:

0. Open the Terminal
1. Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file: `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
2. Change `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`
3. Add `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`
4. Save the file (<kbd>Esc</kbd>⇢<kbd>:</kbd>⇢<kbd>W</kbd>⇢<kbd>X</kbd>
5. Update Grub with: `sudo update-grub`

These settings will ensure that your system boots with the last kernel you chose during boot.

Now reboot, hold the shift key when your system comes back up. You should then see the Grub menu. Choose the Kernel that works for you. That will now be "default".

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: This saved my day. I was trying to switch to the other kernel on my ubuntu 20 VM as I messed up the original kernel/build folder. Thanks.

Comment: This is the solution. Congrats!

Answer (score 11):

If you'd like to always boot specific version by default
you should

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` file. Find `GRUB_DEFAULT` and specify *path to the grub menu entry* (something like `GRUB_DEFAULT='Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-48-generic'`)
2. Run `update-grub`.

Note 1. You can find *grub menu entries* in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
Note 2. I recommend to make a copy of `/etc/default/grub` before modification.

You can also check this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506234925/https://ilya-bystrov.github.io/posts/grub-default-entry-configuration/) - I've created a note for myself some time ago.

Comment: Thank you, this works even when an additional kernel is installed (numbering 1>2 breaks in such cases).

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded kernel version to install an old version of Nvidia driver. After the steps given by user1091774, I find that it is necessary to run `sudo update-initramfs -u`, otherwise DKMS still tries to build Nvidia driver against the latest version of kernel.