# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck at manufacturer logo

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, hp, freeze

I have a HP Envy X360 and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on this fine.  It's been running nicely for a number of months and after an update in the last few days it no longer boots up.

The standard process should be that the HP Logo is displayed, it then asks for my disk decryption password and displays the "Ubuntu" logo at the bottom.  I enter the password and it continues to the X Login, I login there and am then taken to the desktop.

Now - when I power on, I get the HP logo and nothing else.

I can decrypt disk and log in on a terminal prompt with no issues.
If I try using Advanced and selecting a previous Kernel - I can enter the password to decrypt the disk, but it hangs after then.

Live booting is fine.

The 2 kernel versions installed are:
Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.8.0-41-generic
Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.8.0-40-generic

Trying recovery mode takes me into the recovery menu,

dpkg fixes packages - but does not fix the issue.
grub rebuilds the boot menu - but does not fix the issue.

Any help would be appreciated before I consider returning to Windows (Joke).

Comment: I've read some Nvidia drivers can cause issues.

Using:

lshw -c video I get

description: VGA compatible controller
product: Iris Plus Graphics G7
vendor: Intel Corporation

So I'm pretty sure it's not that

Comment: Reinstalling X Server didn't work

Comment: apt install gnome-session gdm3.   Seems to have sorted it partially, using 5.8.0-40 seems to allow me to boot

Comment: Follow this to enable Saved mode in grub 
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308901/setting-older-kernel-version-as-default

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

1. Plugged in a bootable Ubuntu USB.
2. Mounted the drive which Ubuntu was installed on. (using `sudo mount`)
3. `Chroot`ed to the mount directory. (using `sudo chroot`)
4. Did a simple update and upgrade. (`sudo apt update &&‌ sudo apt upgrade`)
5. Restarted the PC and the problem was solved.