# electron apps exit after a few minutes with message Killed

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, chromium, 21.04, electron

I need help figuring out why electron apps get killed after a few minutes of starting them.
That is they do not log ERRORs (neither `dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog` nor when starting from console with `--verbose`) but just exit with printing `Killed` or `terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)` to the console. This also happens when just starting them and just letting them sit. Exactly the same behavior as when manually sending SIGKILL.

Apps that have shown this problem so far :

- google-chrome-stable (official deb/ppa)
- microsoft-teams-preview (official deb/ppa)
- postman (snap)
- insomnia (official deb/ppa)
- visual-studio-code (official deb/ppa)
- signal-desktop (official deb/ppa)

Note, that the problem doesn't always occur, microsoft-teams & google-chrome mostly run just fine. But if it occurs it sticks until a reboot (electron apps) or removing `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` for google-chrome. With chrome & teams i think the problem seems to be related with an unclean exit after a gnome3 crash. However the others are just unusable as they almost always exit after ~2 minutes regardless of if someone is interacting with them or not.

I've tried removing `/tmp/.com.google.*`, `/tmp/.org.chromium.*`, `~/.cache/google-chrome`, `~/.config/insomnia`, `~/snap/postman/current/.config/Postman` but that didn't help...

OS/System :
ubuntu 21.04, 5.11.0-25-generic, Root on ZFS, >16GB free RAM, >100GB free SSD, HP Elitebook 840 G7

If desired i can attach logs.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with all Electron apps (Chromium, VSCode, Slack). The most likely the problem is caused by new version of Linux kernel (5.11.0-25-generic).

**Using previous version works solved the problem.**

This could be achieved the fastest way by using `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT` parameter - here is manual: https://askubuntu.com/a/1308903

Comment: interesting, i think you might be right. One day after a reboot it just worked. for a long time i suspected i never rebooted after installing the apps (i reboot very rarely). but looking at the timestamps of my vmlinuz files it might be that included going to a newer kernel package: from 5.11.0-25-generic to  5.11.0-31-generic (yeah it's the same point release, but...)

Comment: note: this is happening again after updating to ubuntu jammy (5.15.0-18-generic kernel). as it's still in alpha and as electron snaps and chromium (from mint) still work i'll let that slide for now. if anyone knows a fix: _please_ share