# Thinkpad Dock - Ububtu - lost the connexion to the Displays

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, dockstation

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad and a Lenovo dock station....everything was working well until last night. Now the displays connected via the dock are not receiving any signal.
I suppose that is due to the kernel version of Linux used on my computer that is not compatible with the dock. Does some one know which kernel version should I use?
Many thanks

Comment: Why do you think it is related to a kernel version?

Comment: Because to set it up last time I notice that was connected to the kernel version to allow the connection to the dock. I have to take a previous release to make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) and [setting older kernel version as default](https://askubuntu.com/q/1308901/)